# Conditionally Referring to Checkbox Values in Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

```
CASE
  WHEN :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 2' 
   AND :P6_T3_STARTDATE < :P6_T2_DUEDATE 
  THEN
   :P6_T3_STARTDATE = :P6_T2_DUEDATE
  WHEN :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 1' 
   AND :P6_T3_STARTDATE < :P6_T1_DUEDATE 
  THEN
   :P6_T1_DUEDATE
  WHEN :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 1' 
   AND :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 2' 
   AND :P6_T2_DUEDATE > :P6_T1_DUEDATE 
  THEN
   :P6_T2_DUEDATE
  WHEN :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 1' 
   AND :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 2' 
   AND :P6_T2_DUEDATE < :P6_T1_DUEDATE 
  THEN
   :P6_T1_DUEDATE
  ELSE
   'Not Working ' || :P6_T3_STARTDATE
 END
```

I have this statement here trying to conditionally refer to values in a checkbox (Task 1 , Task 2). I get to the else statement every time and I cannot seem to figure out how to properly refer to the values in the checkbox.

Comment: what are the values of each of the page items in the session ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the actual values of the page items in the session this is guessing but I'd give this a shot:

```
CASE
  WHEN :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 2' 
   AND TO_DATE(:P6_T3_STARTDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') < TO_DATE(:P6_T2_DUEDATE ,'DD-MON-YYYY')
  THEN
   'boolean_here'
  WHEN :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 1' 
   AND TO_DATE(:P6_T3_STARTDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') < TO_DATE(:P6_T1_DUEDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') 
  THEN
   :P6_T1_DUEDATE
  WHEN :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 1' 
   AND :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 2' 
   AND TO_DATE(:P6_T2_DUEDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') > TO_DATE(:P6_T1_DUEDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') 
  THEN
   :P6_T2_DUEDATE
  WHEN :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 1' 
   AND :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 2' 
   AND TO_DATE(:P6_T2_DUEDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') < TO_DATE(:P6_T1_DUEDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') 
  THEN
   :P6_T1_DUEDATE
  ELSE
   'Not Working ' || :P6_T3_STARTDATE
 END
```

All page items in apex are considered strings in pl/sql so if you want to do date comparison you'll have to tell the db that you are comparing dates, not strings. You can do that by doing a TO_DATE. I assumed that your date format mask is 'DD-MON-YYYY' but if it isn't you should change that to your own date format mask.

The first `THEN`clause contains an operator as @Barbaros Özhan pointed out so I replaced that with 'boolean_here'.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need a Boolean expression within a `CASE..WHEN` statement.

This part

```
 WHEN :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 2' AND :P6_T3_STARTDATE < :P6_T2_DUEDATE THEN
           :P6_T3_STARTDATE = :P6_T2_DUEDATE
```

, which *violates* this rule , is an **assigment**, not a **boolean** expression. That might be converted to

```
WHEN :P6_TASK3_DEP = 'Task 2' AND :P6_T3_STARTDATE < :P6_T2_DUEDATE THEN
          :P6_T2_DUEDATE
```

instead.

Comment: We should see the complete statement. Is that within a SQL statement, or within a PL/SQL Code Block, and what circumference does it have ..? @Gamecocks20 . *I mean, to which parameter do you assign at the end.*